# if xldate < 0.00: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Tags: string, xlrd

Hello I am trying to read date from an excel cell I am using the code below but it is givng me the error      if xldate < 0.00: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
Can anyone help

```
a = sheet.cell(4,3).value
a_as_date = datetime.date(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(a, 0)[:3])
datetime = xldate.xldate_as_datetime(a, workbook.datemode)
```

Comment: Having the same issue, ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check cell coordinates. If OK, then double-check if the cell format (in the excel cell properties) is Date.

I had a similar problem in a code that previously worked fine and the problem was that the new excel file had an extra column.

This threw error (column 3):

```
        fdate = sheet.cell_value(i, 3)
        y, m, d, h, mm, s = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(fdate, workbook.datemode)
```

While using the new position (column 4) position worked perfectly again:

```
        fdate = sheet.cell_value(i, 4)
        y, m, d, h, mm, s = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(fdate, workbook.datemode)
```